# error in \xdef and cedilla accent

Tags: datatool

Consider the following MWE1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\myOwnCommand}{\c{C}engel}
\begin{document}
This is my surname: \myOwnCommand.
\end{document}
```

MWE1 works just fine.
The cedilla is produced under C.

Now, consider the following MWE2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\xdef\myOwnCommand{\c{C}engel}
\begin{document}
This is my surname: \myOwnCommand.
\end{document}
```

This time, I have defined \myOwnCommand globally using the TEX primitive \xdef, and I wanted \myOwnCommand also to be expanded at once. I'm going to use it inside loops like \DTLforeach in the datatool package.

When I compile MWE2, I get the following error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \myOwnCommand.
<to be read again> 
                   \crcr 
l.15 \xdef\myOwnCommand{\c{C}
                             engel}
?
```

I ask myself where my error is.

Comment: `\xdef` and `\edef` perform exhaustive expansion in the text of the definition, and some things don't work by expansion (the same reason as in your previous question about `filecontents`). `\newcommand` (which uses `\def` internally) doesn't try to expand, so it works. If you want `\xdef`, then use `\protected@xdef` instead

Comment: ok  il try \protected@xdef ...

Comment: Note that not _everything_ will work with `\protected@xdef`, only commands that are designed to work there, namely robust commands (accents like `\c`, commands declared with `\DeclareRobustCommand`, or with `\newrobustcmd` from `etoolbox`...)

Comment: I used
\protected@xdef\myOwnCommand{\c{C}engel} 
instead of
\xdef\myOwnCommand{\c{C}engel}

i got the following error
! You can't use a prefix with `the character @'.
<to be read again> 
                   @
l.15 \protected@
                xdef\myOwnCommand{\c{C}engel}
?

Comment: You need do use `\makeatletter` before using commands with `@` in their name: `\makeatletter \protected@xdef...`. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/134574

Comment: note that other accents work fine,like \v. i dont know but there's something about this \c

Comment: ok i will use \makeatletter .. \makeatother

Comment: it worked using  \makeatletter. :)

Comment: It depends on the definition of the accent. `\v` “works by accident”. Though try `\show\myOwnCommand` after the definition :-) Glad it worked. I'll mark a duplicate (asked by me: I had this same problem some time ago :-)

Comment: the following code also worked: \makeatletter\xdef\myOwnCommand{\v{C}engel}\makeatother

thank you so much @PhelypeOleinik

Comment: yes the link you gave is related to my question here.

Comment: i think it is really safer to use \protected@xdef

Comment: A few points: 1) In `\makeatletter\xdef\myOwnCommand{\v{C}engel}\makeatother` you don't _need_ `\makeatletter...\makeatother`, as there is no command with `@` in the name. 2) Try `\xdef\myOwnCommand{\v{C}engel}\show\myOwnCommand` and see the terminal output. 3) Yes, if the contents of the definition are “text” (accents and such) `\protected@xdef` is safer. 4) If you have an updated distribution you may also try `\ExplSyntaxOn\cs_new_eq:NN\TextExpand\text_expand:n\ExplSyntaxOff\xdef\myOwnCommand{\TextExpand{\c{Ç}engel}}` (`\text_expand:n` does the “protection” here).

Comment: i just realized that \xdef\myOwnCommand{\v{C}engel} as is works (and also using the other accents), but \xdef\myOwnCommand{\c{C}engel} as is does not. initially i thought there is a bug in \c, or something is wrong with its definition. it would be nice though if \xdef\myOwnCommand{\v{C}engel} works for ANY ACCENT. perhaps our TeXperts and LaTeXperts can give this a thought.